# Why high availability of frequencies on a network link results in a higher capacity?

Tags: networking

I am reading a networking book and it says - to have a high capacity(bits per second) link, we need to have a high bandwidth link.

And bandwidth is defined as the range of frequencies available for communication on that particular link. For example, voice grade phone line typically supports a frequency range from 300Hz to 3300Hz, so the bandwidth of this link is 3000Hz.

My question is, why having a large range of available frequencies on a link increases the capacity of that link?

Comment: Start [here](http://computernetworkingsimplified.com/physical-layer/relationship-bandwidth-data-rate-channel-capacity/).

Answer (score 0):

Information is conveyed by the change in values in a signal. High data rate is achieved by making higher frequency signals.

If a link supported higher bandwidth, that means it supports high frequency transmission. Which translated to being able to transfer high frequency signal.

This is how high bandwidth correlates to high capacity for a network link.

[Source](http://computernetworkingsimplified.com/physical-layer/relationship-bandwidth-data-rate-channel-capacity/)